# Is it possible to bypass model_save_before observers?

Tags: event-observer, model, sales

I have a strange issue which I think I narrowed down to observers occasionally not being triggered.

#### Situation:

An Observer for `sales_order_invoice_save_before` (in the `global` node), serializes some custom attributes. In most cases, this works fine, but in ~5% of the cases I get the string `Array` in `sales_flat_order_invoice`, as if the observer was not triggered.

I did not find out yet, what these orders/invoices have in common, but I want to be sure that I am on the right track and the issue isnt't somewhere else.

#### Question:

In which cases is it possible that models are saved without dispatching their `{$eventPrefix}_save_before` event? I can only imagine raw SQL queries but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: `{$eventPrefix}_save_before` is hardcoded in `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::_beforeSave`. So, unless you override `_beforeSave` completely for a given model class, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Can you find a common pattern for those 5% of the invoices?

Comment: Can you post here the observer method and the config.xml definition? Does your module have the proper `depends` node in the module definition file from app/etc/modules?

Comment: It looks like this error has another reason. I'll leave the question open in case somebody has a general answer, but I eventually solved my problem in a different way, case closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is actually not possible. The observed behavior might have been a side effect of another observer that was registered for the same event.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you is, override the event into any extension or include that file into local and then change the code according to your requirement.